# setPreference method of FirefoxOptions is not getting recognized through Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I am pretty new to C# and integrating with firefox.

So this might be a very basic newbie question :)

I have this code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

options.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
options.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
options.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
options.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
options.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in PDF viewer
```

The setPreference is marked with red. It is not recognized.

I have following installed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, Int32)

[`FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, Int32)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions_SetPreference_2.htm) defines:

```
public void SetPreference(
    string preferenceName,
    int preferenceValue
)
```

So you need to replace:

```
options.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
```

With:

```
options.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
```

---

### FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, String)

[`FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, String)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions_SetPreference_4.htm) defines:

```
public void SetPreference(
    string preferenceName,
    string preferenceValue
)
```

So you need to replace:

```
options.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
options.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
```

With:

```
options.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
options.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf");
```

---

### FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, Boolean)

[`FirefoxOptions.SetPreference Method (String, Boolean)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxOptions_SetPreference.htm) defines:

```
public void SetPreference(
    string preferenceName,
    bool preferenceValue
)
```

So you need to replace:

```
options.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
options.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

With:

```
options.SetPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
options.SetPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
```

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/documents");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("IRS Form 872-C")).click();

Comment: @KeepDevelopingDK That seems to be a new error all together. Can you raise a new question for your new requirement please?